# Chrome extension weird errors: expected integer, found number?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

[image]

This error only occurred on some windows machine (win10, win11)，My PC is windows 10, but it works ok.

Some code snippet:

```
chrome.windows.create(
      {
        url: url,
        type: 'popup',
        width: 1280,
        height: 800,
        top: window.screen.height / 2 - 400,
        left: window.screen.width / 2 - 640,
      },
```

- Windows system: win10|win11
- Chrome version: 100 (64bit)
- Chrome extension manifest version: 2

Comment: Your `top` and `left` are fractional numbers because `width` or `height` is odd and thus not divisible by 2. Use rounding.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I will try now and give feedback soon.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved by rounding the `top` and `left` to integer, thanks for @wOxxOm 's comment!